# Dataframe and pass a variable to fill in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. I have a dataframe which is like this:

```
      name             comment        
0      A            I enjoy this lovely moment.
1      B            I can't believe this was the worst day ever.
2      C            The hotel was amazing.
3      A            I am overwhelmed by this lovely journey.
4      C            Food is good as well as having a nice time.
...
```

I have to create a new column in that dataframe and fill this column with a variable named 'a' for each row.

```
code for my dataset is:
```

a = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.decode('utf-8')))

```
Can you please help me please please.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function `predict` that receives one comment and returns the prediction value, then create a new column using the following code:

```py
rawData['prediction'] = rawData['comment'].apply(lambda x: predict(x))
```

To create a function in python the syntax is the following:

```py
def predict(comment):
    # code that does the prediction
    return prediction
```

Comment: Can you explain to me on how to create the function predict?

Comment: Actually I have implemented the codes from this link : https://www.kaggle.com/eray1yildiz/using-lstms-with-attention-for-emotion-recognition/comments

Comment: I have removed the #visualization part and I have print(label_probs) where it predicts an emotion for the sentence form sample_text

Answer (score 0):

well, I'm assuming you've a DataFrame named rawData having two columns `['name', comment']`.
To add a new column in rawData, you can add a line:

```
rawData['prediction'] = Prediction
```

and you will get rawData having three columns ie `['name', comment', 'prediction']`

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that you already have Prediction variable.

and to predict something like above you mentioned, you need to create a function having an architecture of whole model with training dataset!!

Comment: Since you have probabilities, convert those probabilities into labels.

Answer (score 0):

TO convert probabilities use

```
label_probs, attentions = model_with_attentions.predict(encoded_samples)
label_probs = {id2label[_id]: prob for (label, _id), prob in zip(label2id.items(),label_probs[0])}
```

and here you'll have predicted emotions

```
emotions = [label for label, _ in label_probs.items()]
```

and then insert this emotions variable as I explained above in my first comment.

Comment: Here, in the above code it predicts the encoded_samples, so insert the predicted emotions in that DataFrame.

Comment: or use your own test dataset to predict the emotions and insert this column(predicted emotions) in your test dataset.

Comment: Sir, I have not understand.. can you explain to me please.